# Suggestions to Optimize MySQL Query based on query plan

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query running on MySQL database. The query is taking more time as we have more no.of records in the orders table. Please suggest tips to optimize the query based on the query plan.

> mysql> explain SELECT DISTINCT
>   dt.customer_id,dt.email,dt.title,dt.fname,dt.lname,dt.
>   work_phone,dt.mobile_phone,dt.home_phone,dt.blacklist_reason,dt.
>   domain,dt.domain_group,dt.my_account_flag,dt.marketing_preference,dt.
>   city,dt.address1,dt.address2,dt.state,dt.
>   country,dt.zip,dt.country_code FROM (SELECT
>   cc.customer_id,cc.email,cc.title,cc.fname,cc.lname,
>   cc.work_phone,cc.mobile_phone,cc.home_phone,cc.blacklist_reason,
>   cc.domain,cc.domain_group,cc.my_account_flag,cc.marketing_preference,
>   ca.city,ca.address1,ca.address2,ca.state,
>   ca.country,ca.zip,ca.country_code,odd.order_date FROM customer cc
>   INNER JOIN customer_address ca ON cc.customer_id=ca.customer_id left
>   outer join order_delivery_details odd on
>   cc.customer_id=odd.customer_id WHERE   cc.lname = 'XXXXXX' and
>   ca.address_purpose='XXXX'   and  ( cc.domain in ( 'XXXXXX_IE' ) ||
>   cc.domain_group in  ( 'XXXXX' , 'YYYYYY' ) )   order by odd.order_date
>   desc) dt LIMIT 0,500;

The SQL:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT dt.customer_id,
    dt.email,
    dt.title,
    dt.fname,
    dt.lname,
    dt. work_phone,
    dt.mobile_phone,
    dt.home_phone,
    dt.blacklist_reason,
    dt. domain,
    dt.domain_group,
    dt.my_account_flag,
    dt.marketing_preference,
    dt. city,
    dt.address1,
    dt.address2,
    dt.state,
    dt. country,
    dt.zip,
    dt.country_code 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            cc.customer_id,
            cc.email,
            cc.title,
            cc.fname,
            cc.lname, 
            cc.work_phone,
            cc.mobile_phone,
            cc.home_phone,
            cc.blacklist_reason, 
            cc.domain,
            cc.domain_group,
            cc.my_account_flag,
            cc.marketing_preference, 
            ca.city,
            ca.address1,
            ca.address2,
            ca.state, 
            ca.country,
            ca.zip,
            ca.country_code,
            odd.order_date 
        FROM 
            customer cc 
        INNER JOIN customer_address ca ON cc.customer_id=ca.customer_id 
        left outer join order_delivery_details odd on cc.customer_id=odd.customer_id 
        WHERE   cc.lname = 'XXXXXX' 
        and     ca.address_purpose='XXXX'   
        and  ( cc.domain in ( 'XXXXXX_IE' ) 
            or cc.domain_group in  ( 'XXXXX' , 'YYYYYY' ) 
            )   
        order by odd.order_date desc
    ) dt 
    LIMIT 0,500;
```

[image]

Thanks for your response. I cannot move order by outside of subquery because the main query doesn't include order_date column.

Here is the requirement. We should search the customer based on search criteria and order the customers based on his latest order_date. Customers can have mutliple orders, we have to pick the latest order's order_date and sort the customer.

First I'm listing all customers joining with orders table and ordering all the records based on order_date.
Once all the records are ordered based on order_date, there is a much chance that there are multiply records for same customer if customer has multiple orders.

Now I'm applying distinct on top of it excluding the order_date in order to get dictinct customer details.

Thanks,
Chandu

Comment: The ORDER BY should probably be moved outside the subquery. MySQL _may_ currently keep the order through DISTINCT, but no other RDBMS does and i doubt MySQL will in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I cannot move order by outside of subquery because the main query doesn't include order_date column.

Comment: Do all orders not have a record on the order_delivery_details table? As you are ordering to get the most recent orders, do you care about the customers who have no orders? Those customers without an order will land up being sorted last and so (with many customers) are highly unlikely to be included in the latest 500 and an inner join is likely to be faster.

Comment: Yes, for some customers there won't be records in orders table. We need to consider that customers as well. So I used left outer join rather than inner join.

Comment: On average how many orders does a customer have? ie, do you have 10000 customers each with 100 orders, or 100 customers each with 10000 orders?

Comment: @KickStart : On a average there will be 10 orders for each customer. But there are scenarios where in a single customer has around 50000 orders.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the query so it matches your description of what it shall do: You want to see a list of customer addresses ordered by the customer's last order. To get an entry *per address*, you *group by address*. And to order by last order date descending, you order by max(order_date) desc.

```
SELECT 
  cc.customer_id,
  cc.email,
  cc.title,
  cc.fname,
  cc.lname, 
  cc.work_phone,
  cc.mobile_phone,
  cc.home_phone,
  cc.blacklist_reason, 
  cc.domain,
  cc.domain_group,
  cc.my_account_flag,
  cc.marketing_preference, 
  ca.city,
  ca.address1,
  ca.address2,
  ca.state, 
  ca.country,
  ca.zip,
  ca.country_code
FROM  customer cc 
INNER JOIN customer_address ca ON cc.customer_id = ca.customer_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_delivery_details odd on cc.customer_id = odd.customer_id 
WHERE cc.lname = 'XXXXXX' 
AND ca.address_purpose='XXXX'   
AND (cc.domain in ( 'XXXXXX_IE' ) OR cc.domain_group in ('XXXXX', 'YYYYYY'))   
GROUP BY ca.id
order by max(odd.order_date) desc
LIMIT 0,500;
```

This should be faster, because you simply tell the dbms *what* you want to see and the dbms can find the best way *how* to achieve this.

Comment: Group by is killing my query as I have millions of records. I tried to execute the above query on my DB server and the query is taking so many minutes. I killed it

Comment: Sorry to hear that. This is the straight-forward way to write the query and the dbms should be able to execute it in the best possible way. Do you have indexes on both cc.lname and ca.address_purpose? You should.

Comment: Another thought: Maybe the intermediate result is too big, because of too many delivery details. You might fare better by not joining order_delivery_details at all, but `order by (select max(order_date) from order_delivery_details where customer_id = cc.customer_id) desc`. It may be worth a try.

Comment: Yaa My intermediate results is too big as you mentioned.I have indexes on cc.lname and no index on ca.address_purpose as it holds only two possible values.

I will try your second suggestion and will let you know. Thank you

Comment: While this seems to do what you have written you require, this does not do the same as your actual current query. This will return one row per customer while your original query will potentially return many rows per customer, ordered by the date and then use DESTINCT to exclude all but one of those per customer. How distinct will affect the order is something I am not certain about (it would seem it would in effect do a GROUP BY on the other columns, and GROUP BY does an implicit ORDER BY).

Comment: Once you move order_delivery_details to a subquery in ORDER BY, you don't need GROUP BY (or DISTINCT) anymore. And anyhow, all queries should return one row per customer address. I don't see how one of the queries could suddenly return only one record per customer.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't put it well. My point was that the original query has a sub query that brings back potentially multiple rows per customer. These are ordered by the order_date. But the outer query uses DISTINCT to remove the duplicates; as I understand it MySQL uses GROUP BY processing to do the DISTINCT, and GROUP BY has an implicit ORDER BY. So I suspect it could lose the ordering in order_date order. Your query makes more sense to me and seems to match the requirements, but possibly doesn't match the original (slow) query.

Comment: @Kickstart: Okay, I misunderstood. Your observation is good, as the MySQL documentation clearly says that GROUP BY implements ORDER BY and DISTINCT implements GROUP BY. So it seems likely that DISTINCT involuntarily destroys the pre-built order in the OP's query. Surprisingly however, this seems not to be the case. Here is my test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e689e/1 .

Comment: Kickstart : I got the same doubt initially when designing the query. When I used distinct on the result set, luckily it is retaining the order sorted by order by clause and it served my purpose.

Comment: Can I suggest that you try @ThorstenKettner answer, but remove the _OR cc.domain_group in ('XXXXX', 'YYYYYY')_ and with an index added covering lname AND domain . Just interested in how much quicker this would be (and hence whether it would be worth having 2 fully indexed queries each limited to 500 with the results unioned together, then just selecting the latest 500 from that small result set).

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner : I removed the left outer join and added the order by clause as suggested. Thank you the query perfomance improved :) but not upto the mark we expect it to run. Is there a way to optimize select max(order_date) by creating some sort of functional index?

Comment: @Kickstart : The domain name field will have only a limited values (say max 10 distinct values). Is it still worthy to add index covering both lname and domain and give a try ??

Comment: @user2621477 - It is worth it. Part of the issue with your query (and this solution) is that it has no good index to use on the _customer_ table, only an index on lname which doesn't narrow things down enough. It used either domain OR domain_group so with the current query you cannot just add an index on one or both of those (as MySQL will only use one index). It might be possible to add and index on lname and domain, and another on lname and domain_group , then you can have 2 queries UNIONed together (this way one index is used for each unioned query).

Comment: @user2621477: In order to speed up the max(order_date) thing, you can of course create an index on order_delivery_details (customer_id, order_date), so the table doesn't have to be read at all, as all the information is in the index, even sorted by customer.

Comment: @user2621477: In order to speed up the main query, we should look at it from a less technical point of view. You want the addresses of all 'Smith' in certain domains (which in itself seems a little strange). Then, when looking for a certain domain; wouldn't that belong to a particular domain group? So rather than `domain in ('abc123') or domain_group in ('efg','hij')` you'd get `domain_group in ('abc','efg','hij') and (domain in ('abc123') or domain_group in ('efg','hij'))`. Thus an index on customer(lname, domain_group) could be used, because domain_group *must* be in ('abc','efg','hij').

Comment: @Thorsten : This is a dynamic query. We have a few search fields like fname, lname, email, order number etc. The user can enter all the details or a few of them. So dynamically the query is going to change based on input. I can't simple create combined index on (lname, domain_group). Coming to domain & domain group logic, the same rule applies here as well, the input may send domain or domain group or both. Based on input we are dynamically building the query.

Comment: @chandu: Okay, then there is no way to optimize the query thus. Such queries depend very much on the parameters given. I suppose that the query without order_delivery_details would usually be rather fast. So you might want to store the last order date redundantly in the customer table to also get the sorting process fast.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : Storing the last order date in customer table was also another option we had on the list. But there are millions of records already existing, we have to first update all those records and also have to make changes in create order journey, manage order journey etc to update the last order column in the customer table. So we are thinking to optimize the query rather than doing all that stuff.
And once again thanks for your suggestion which improved the query execution time :)

Comment: Populating that field should be fairly easy, and if you want to avoid modifying lots of scripts to keep that field up to date then you can cheat a bit and just put the processing in a trigger on the current orders table.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the index it is choosing to use on the customer table is just for the lname field, but that doesn't seem to narrow the results down much. Think you would need to add a couple of indexes, one covering lname and domain and the other covering lname and domain_group. Then you can have 2 unioned queries.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT dt.customer_id,
    dt.email,
    dt.title,
    dt.fname,
    dt.lname,
    dt. work_phone,
    dt.mobile_phone,
    dt.home_phone,
    dt.blacklist_reason,
    dt. domain,
    dt.domain_group,
    dt.my_account_flag,
    dt.marketing_preference,
    dt. city,
    dt.address1,
    dt.address2,
    dt.state,
    dt. country,
    dt.zip,
    dt.country_code 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            cc.customer_id,
            cc.email,
            cc.title,
            cc.fname,
            cc.lname, 
            cc.work_phone,
            cc.mobile_phone,
            cc.home_phone,
            cc.blacklist_reason, 
            cc.domain,
            cc.domain_group,
            cc.my_account_flag,
            cc.marketing_preference, 
            ca.city,
            ca.address1,
            ca.address2,
            ca.state, 
            ca.country,
            ca.zip,
            ca.country_code,
            odd.order_date 
        FROM 
            customer cc 
        INNER JOIN customer_address ca ON cc.customer_id=ca.customer_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN order_delivery_details odd on cc.customer_id=odd.customer_id 
        WHERE   cc.lname = 'XXXXXX' 
        AND     ca.address_purpose='XXXX'   
        AND  cc.domain_group in  ( 'XXXXX' , 'YYYYYY' )   
        UNION
        SELECT 
            cc.customer_id,
            cc.email,
            cc.title,
            cc.fname,
            cc.lname, 
            cc.work_phone,
            cc.mobile_phone,
            cc.home_phone,
            cc.blacklist_reason, 
            cc.domain,
            cc.domain_group,
            cc.my_account_flag,
            cc.marketing_preference, 
            ca.city,
            ca.address1,
            ca.address2,
            ca.state, 
            ca.country,
            ca.zip,
            ca.country_code,
            odd.order_date 
        FROM 
            customer cc 
        INNER JOIN customer_address ca ON cc.customer_id=ca.customer_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN order_delivery_details odd on cc.customer_id=odd.customer_id 
        WHERE   cc.lname = 'XXXXXX' 
        AND     ca.address_purpose='XXXX'   
        AND  cc.domain in ( 'XXXXXX_IE' ) 
        ORDER BY odd.order_date desc
    ) dt 
    LIMIT 0,500;
```

I am not sure your original query needed an inner and an outer query. MySQL will let you sort on a column you are not returning. However it looks like the major issue is indexing, and you can't order the results of a unioned query by a column that isn't being returned from the 2 unioned queries.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    cc.customer_id,
    cc.email,
    cc.title,
    cc.fname,
    cc.lname, 
    cc.work_phone,
    cc.mobile_phone,
    cc.home_phone,
    cc.blacklist_reason, 
    cc.domain
    cc.domain_group,
    cc.my_account_flag,
    cc.marketing_preference, 
    ca.city,
    ca.address1,
    ca.address2,
    ca.state, 
    ca.country,
    ca.zip,
    ca.country_code,
FROM 
    customer cc 
INNER JOIN customer_address ca ON cc.customer_id=ca.customer_id 
left outer join order_delivery_details odd on cc.customer_id=odd.customer_id 
WHERE
    cc.lname = 'XXXXXX' 
    AND ca.address_purpose='XXXX'   
    AND ( cc.domain in ( 'XXXXXX_IE' ) OR cc.domain_group in  ( 'XXXXX' , 'YYYYYY' ) )
ORDER BY odd.order_date DESC
LIMIT 0,500
```

You don't need a sub-select to get what you want.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. Will try once tomorrow and will let you know the performance of the query. Thanks for the suggestion.